# MySQL scheduled event wasn't executed

Tags: mysql

I created an event for a job of every one hour in MySQL, it's seems all right in the SQLyog client. But several hours passed, it was actually not executed. I don't know why, hope someone can help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help if you share the CREATE EVENT command you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you also run:

```
set global event_scheduler = 1;
```

Comment: how can i query about this parameter? i want to first confirm.

Comment: Thanks, that's the problem. I use 'select @@global.event_sheduler' to check and got 'OFF'. now i have enabled it.